# Receive Firebase Cloud Messaging without SDK

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a web application that uses websockets to receive real time updates. Since I don't use the websocket connection for anything else, and scaling websocket servers is a pain, I'm considering moving the messaging part to Firebase Cloud Messaging.

It seems a pretty straight forward port for my web app.

However, the web app comes with a companion desktop app that some customers use, that is written in QT+Python. Is there any way to receive the FCM messages in a different client than the official SDKs?

Comment: The wire protocol for receiving downstream FCM messages is not publicly documented.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that writes off this option.